# How to JSON format an array of arrays?

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have a basic array like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Ray"
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "Anthony"
    }
]
```

And i need to return a series of these arrays as part of a single json message.  I can't seem to get it right according to: http://jsonlint.com/.   For example, i have groups of people. Each group is an array of people and each group should be a distinct element of the parent array.   How should it be formatted?

To clarify:

```
group1: ray, anthony
group2: john, mike
group3: ed, dan
```

and so on...

Comment: What does your attempted format look like?

Comment: Is you basic array in PHP or JavaScript? Are you groups PHP object in an array?

Comment: PHP or JavaScript? Pick one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just group them by two's, from PHP create the structure, then as usual, use `json_encode()`. Example:

```
$groups = array(
    'group1' => array(
        array('id' => 4, 'name' => 'Ray'),
        array('id' => 5, 'name' => 'Anthony'),
    ),
    'group2' => array(
        array('id' => 6, 'name' => 'john'),
        array('id' => 7, 'name' => 'mike'),
    ),
    'group3' => array(
        array('id' => 8, 'name' => 'ed'),
        array('id' => 9, 'name' => 'dan'),
    ),
);

echo '<pre>';
print_r(json_encode($groups, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
```

Should yield something like:

```
{
    "group1": [
        {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "Ray"
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "name": "Anthony"
        }
    ],
    "group2": [
        {
            "id": 6,
            "name": "john"
        },
        {
            "id": 7,
            "name": "mike"
        }
    ],
    "group3": [
        {
            "id": 8,
            "name": "ed"
        },
        {
            "id": 9,
            "name": "dan"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i guess this works:

```
{
    "g1": [
        {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "Ray"
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "name": "Anthony"
        }
    ],
    "g2": [
        {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "Mike"
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "name": "John"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i like this way:

```
var  groups = [
"G1" : {
    "11" : {
        "id" : 11,
        "name" : "jhon"
    },
    "3" : {
        "id" : 3,
        "name" : "erik"
    }
},
"G2" : {
    "8" : {
        "id" : 8,
        "name" : "jean"
    },
    "4" : {
        "id" : 4,
        "name" : "jim"
    }
}
]
```

inside any group the key of any object is the ID (string format) of the person, to easy access of its data.

ex.

```
group.G2[8]; // return jean object
```

PHP format:

```
$g = array(
    'G1' => array(
        '11' => array('id' => 11, 'name' => 'jhon'),
        '3' =>array('id' => 3, 'name' => 'erik')
    ),
    'G2' => array(
        '8' => array('id' => 8, 'name' => 'jean'),
        '4' => array('id' => 4, 'name' => 'jim')
    )
);
```